# Can bee stings be treated with onions?

Tags: alternative-medicine, toxicology, bees

[Someone told me that when you have a bee sting you should cut an onion in half and apply it to the sting for 30min - or even better make onion puree and apply it](http://www.motherearthnews.com/natural-health/natural-remedy-for-insect-stings-zmaz00onzgoe.aspx).

This sounds a bit like folk-medicine (not saying that this means it's not true). Is there any prove (medical research, studies, etc.) that this helps? And if yes, how does it help?

The above link states

> the pain will diminish almost immediately

Others claim that it can prevent swelling or make it much less severe and helps with faster healing.

Comment: At the moment I don't see a specific claim. `can be treated` doesn't mean anything. Is the claim about less swelling? Is it about less pain?

Comment: @Christian: I've updated the question

Comment: Onion extract gels are researched for scar healing-http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3390235/